# Is it possible to create with Visual Studio a class library assembly which is platform indepedent?

Tags: .net, clr

Can I create a class library with Visual Studio which is platform indepedent, meaning it does not depend on .NET Framework?

What I mean is this: ECMA 335 defines CLI and the basic types, so I am trying to see how to create an assembly which is just ECMA 335 compliant, and platform independent. I just want an assembly which has simple code with types defined by ECMA 335. Is it possible?

Or, since the compiler is actually part of the .NET runtime (Microsoft's .NET Framework in this case), there's no way you could actually do this?

Comment: What type of code are you writing where you won't be depending on framework supplied types such as `int` or `string`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Imagine simple code which only implements some logic. This shouldn't be that common.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever What do you mean by "framework supplied types such as int or string"? These types are actually part of ECMA 335, they are not framework's types

Comment: int and string are parts of Common Types System (CTS)

Comment: .NET assemblies are platform-independent by design.  Problem is that the reference assemblies you use often are not.  Creating a .NETStandard library is as close as you can get.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, I know about .NET Standard, but I don't understand, why can't I create a class library which let's say has only this code: 
```class static MyMath { static int Add(int a, int b) { return a + b; } }```
This is ECMA 335 compliant code

Comment: Shouldn't I be able somehow to create an ECMA 335 assembly which that code? Why does it have to depend on a specific library? Or is it how the runtime actually works? It actually needs the referencing to those framework libraries?

Comment: It may look like you don't have any dependencies.  But you do, on Windows it is mscorlib.dll, on Linux it is System.Private.Corelib.  These assemblies are filled to the brim with highly platform-specific code.  A lot of which is not available on Linux.  By targeting .NETStandard you get a reference assembly (netstandard.dll) that ensures you can't accidentally use an api that is not available on one of the platforms.

Comment: For my sample code above, what if I call the `Add` method on a platform with a .NET Runtime which uses same DLL name `mscorlib.dll`? It would work right? Is this why for example I  can add as a reference a .NET Framework class library to a Xamarin Android project, and call that method fine from the Android app? Because I see Mono.Android has a mscorlib.dll as well

Comment: Hmm, I see `mscorlib` part of ECMA 335 as well.. What did you mean by `System.Private.Corelib`, which .NET Runtime does it belong?